# MSVC yields incorrect square root for std::uint64_t at and around max. Bug or expected?

Tags: c++, msvcrt

**Question:**
While I was writing some unit tests for integer pairing functions, I noticed a "bug" that keeps cropping up. Both std::sqrt and std::sqrtl yield the same incorrect results near the max std::uint64_t values. Is this is simply to be expected because of floating point rounding error or a bug in microsoft's compiler? If it is to be expected, then is there a way to circumvent this issue without resorting to 128 bit data or using an iterative algorithm to increase precision? Maybe a compiler flag I should be aware of?

**Example:**
With these pairing functions, to unpair an input you have to get the floor of the square root of the input, which I cannot get around the max values. I've abstracted the issue into a simple example for demonstration:

```cpp
    auto max = std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max(); //18446744073709551615
    auto square_root = std::floorl(std::sqrtl(max));       //4294967296.0000000
    auto max2 = max - 1;
    auto square_root2 = std::floorl(std::sqrtl(max2));     //4294967296.0000000
    auto max3 = max - 2;
    auto square_root3 = std::floorl(std::sqrtl(max3));     //4294967296.0000000
    auto max4 = max - 5;
    auto square_root4 = std::floorl(std::sqrtl(max4));     //4294967296.0000000
    auto max5 = max / 10;
    auto square_root5 = std::floorl(std::sqrtl(max5));     //1358187913.0000000
```

According to wolframalpha, the correct values for the first 4 square roots by themselves is as follows

```
//(respectively)
4294967295.99999999988358467817306518554529727818955797
4294967295.99999999976716935634613037108743911275823190
4294967295.99999999965075403451919555662642550370602178
4294967295.99999999930150806903839111322445201482408715

//To clarify, the floor of 4294967295.99999999930 should be 
//4294967295.0, where the code produces
//4294967296.0
```

Notes:

- I should say that I don't anticipate this causing a problem for pairing, this is more of a conceptual question and I'll file a bug if this is not expected behavior.
- I'm using visual studio 2017 and see this behavior in both x86 and x64 builds
- More information on pairing functions at: http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf (though I'm not looking for a different solution)

**Extra information**

Thank you to @Phil1970 for the concise answer and explanation- In addition to his answer I'd like to share an interesting excerpt I found from [the article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) [shared by @HongOoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421926/msvc-yields-incorrect-square-root-for-stduint64-t-at-and-around-max-bug-or-ex?noredirect=1#comment101324791_57421926) as it relates to the question I posted

> Brown [1981] has proposed axioms for floating-point that include most of the existing floating-point hardware. However, proofs in this system cannot verify the algorithms of sections Cancellation and Exactly Rounded Operations, which require features not present on all hardware. Furthermore, Brown's axioms are more complex than simply defining operations to be performed exactly and then rounded. Thus proving theorems from Brown's axioms is usually more difficult than proving them assuming operations are exactly rounded.
>
> There is not complete agreement on what operations a floating-point standard should cover. In addition to the basic operations +, -, × and /, the IEEE standard also specifies that square root, remainder, and conversion between integer and floating-point be correctly rounded. It also requires that conversion between internal formats and decimal be correctly rounded  **(except for very large numbers).**

while "correctly rounded (except for very large numbers)" sounds a bit dubious to me, implying that correct rounding is not *required* by the floating-point specification for large numbers, I believe the behavior experienced in the example is indeed expected. The take away here is that floating-point error and rounding is not limited to subtle nuances in the mantessa working with small numbers past the decimal. It is also important to be aware of the (in)accuracy of large numbers with implicit conversion to and from integer data types.

Comment: I can't catch, where is the mentioned error.

Comment: the floor of 4294967295.99999999930 should be 4294967295.0 not 4294967296.0. I will clarify this, thank you.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Confused with the round.

Comment: Try outputting `static_cast<long double>(max)`, `static_cast<long double>(max2)`, etc. You may find those results explain what you are seeing

Comment: If you do `double d = 4294967295.99999999930;` then `d` will be equal to 4294967296.0 as this is the nearest double that can be represented. You are allowed to write more digits that what can be represented.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @M.M This is true, I knew that it was being implicitly cast to a double or long double depending on the function, but I didn’t think about the fact that truncation to a double (of the same size as std::uint64_t) would lose precision by GAINING value. I had assumed that it would at worst round down to the next order of magnitude and since the pairing function is a bijection whose result requires a maximum of twice as many bits as the input types, that the output from pair(uint32_t max, uint32_t max) should have “symmetrical” rounding and produce invertible results.

Comment: @HongOoi While I appreciate the link and agree it's important to understand the IEEE floating-point standard, this an incredibly broad paper that, if at all, only lightly covers the exact case stated by the question. I will post the brief excerpt that I could find from the paper as it relates to the specific question. If you have more specific information to add please feel free to quote so we can learn more about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::uint64_t` is 64 bits

In the case of Visual Studio a `double` or a `long double` is also 64 bit.

A double in IEE 754 format has 53 bit for the mantissa: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.

64 - 53 bit = 11 bit. 11 bit consisting of 1 is 2047. Since number are rounded to nearest double, we get `18446744073709551616` for any number between `max - 1023` to `max` inclusively. And we get `18446744073709549568` for numbers between `max - 3070` and `max - 1024` inclusively. The difference between these 2 numbers is 2048 (2^11). So a double with a value around 2^64 is precise to ±2048.

MSVC use 64 bit long double. Other compiler might use 80 bit or even 128: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double.

I used the following code to test a few offset from `max`

```
void test(std::uint64_t offset)
{
    auto max = std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max(); //18446744073709551615

    std::cout << "max - " << std::setw(10) << offset << " : " 
        << std::setprecision(20) << static_cast<double>(max - offset) << "\n";
}
```

Here is the output for some numbers:

```
max -          0 : 18446744073709551616
max -       1023 : 18446744073709551616
max -       1024 : 18446744073709549568
max -       2047 : 18446744073709549568
max -       2048 : 18446744073709549568
max -       3070 : 18446744073709549568
max -       3071 : 18446744073709547520
```

**Added information**

Yes it is expected that converting an integer value will loose some precision if it required more bits that what is allowed by the mantissa of the floating point number. Usually, with `double` it is not a problem for usual application as one nee a number bigger than 2^53 (9.007e15) to start losing precision when converting to an IEEE 754 double.

I don't know if conversion from an integer to a double need to be rounded or if it is implementation defined. In the opposite direction, it is always truncated. Where converting text to an double (either at compile-time or run-time), I believe it is always rounded to the nearest representable value.

Having said that, the result before rounding for the square root like `4294967295.99999999930150806903839111322445201482408715` cannot be represented in a double with enough precision. It would require 20 significant digits to represent `4294967295.9999999993` and a 64 bit double has about 15 significatif digits.

So what can you do?

- Ignore the problem if you don't need to handle that much precision. Use a number around 2^50 for your **max** in unit testing.
- Use another compiler like **Intel** or **gcc** that support larger floating point types.
- Use a library specifically made for large precision floating point computation.
- Estimate the square root using some formula and possibly iterations.
- Convert back the number to a integer. Check if less than 2^32. If so square it and if above original number, substract one.

Comment: So because of double's conversion/truncation rules, max uint64_t down to -1023 actually "truncates" to a greater value? This is fascinating, I'm surprised they don't use a lookup table uint64_t std::sqrtl() to avoid this bizarre result. While I can surmise part of the answer to my question from your response, it would be nice for others to maybe elaborate on your test as it relates to the original question(s). Additionally, do you know if these truncation rules are expounded upon in the c++ standard or IEEE754 specification? Thank you!

Comment: I have added some details to the question. It is definitively the expected behavior (except maybe some minor details).

Comment: Note that if using gcc on Windows with long double you need to be careful,  some builds are bugged due to incorrectly offloading to MSVC libraries.  It works correctly in latest version of mingw-w64.